# I have a syntax error for incorrect string concatenation in python, and I've tried everything

Tags: python, syntax

So whenever I try to run a program I have I keep getting a syntax error for what I assume to be incorrect string concatenation.

I have tried using single quotes, and looking up correct syntax for string concatenation, but I think that something different happens when you are concatenating a string and a str(var) function.

the error code is as follows:

```
floater1 = random.uniform(1.234543,6.948735)
floater2 = random.uniform(1.234543,6.948735)
print("what is" + str(floater1) " times " + str(floater2) + "?")
```

So the error comes up in the line:
    `print("what is" + str(floater1) " times " + str(floater2) + "?")`

where the double quotes surrounding  `times` are.

Comment: Put a `+` between `str(floater1)` and `" times "`.

Comment: Or use `print("what is {} times {}?".format(floater1, floater2))`.

Comment: Concatenating strings with `+` is considered inefficient and bad practice in Python. See https://pyformat.info/ for alternatives.

Comment: Hint: notice how you **don't** get an error between `"what is"` and `str(floater1)`, but you **do** between `str(floater1)` and `" times "`? What's different between those two places?

Comment: Thank you, I can see how concatenating strings with +s can be frustrating, so I will switch to a more efficient format

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
print("what is" + str(floater1)+" times " + str(floater2) + "?")
```

Comment: Thank you, feels bad to have wasted time on a little mistake

Answer (score 0):

The correct answer is:

```py
print("what is " + str(floater1) + " times " + str(floater2) + "?")
```

You want to print a combination of variables (`floater1` and `floater2`) and strings. So you must use quotes before and after every string:

- string 1: "what is " (the space in the end is to separate from the upcoming variable)
- variable 1: floater1
- string 2: " times "
- variable 2: floater2
- string 3: "?"

Or, if it is Python > 3.6, you can use f-string (check the `f` before quote) and use your variables inside `{}` -- this way you opne and close quote only once:

```py
print(f"what is {str(floater1)} times {str(floater2)}?")
```

In case you want to learn more about f-string, here is some info on [PEP 498](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0498/).

Comment: thank you, seems like there are many easier ways to format this, so I will try to make it look better.